# How do I create and use System.Diagnostics.PerformanceData.CounterSet?

Tags: .net, powershell, performancecounter

I have got performance counters in my .NET application which I have created with the `PerformanceCounterCategory.Create` method, passing in a `CounterCreationDataCollection`.

I have just been playing with Powershell's `Get-Counter` command which takes a `-ListSet` parameter. If you execute:

```
Get-Counter -ListSet * | select countersetname | sort countersetname
```

you will see a list that is very similar to what you see in perfmon.exe's list of available counter categories.

The problem is that my category does not get returned from the above command.

Evidently "counter category" and "counter set" are different concepts. The closest I can find in .NET is [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceData.CounterSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancedata.counterset(v=vs.110).aspx). The problem is there is no good documentation or samples on how to create these "counter sets".

Is `CounterSet` the thing I need? How do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this was an (undiagnosed) anomaly with my Powershell session. When I ran this in my Powershell ISE (non-admin) I was getting the following error:

```
> Get-Counter -ListSet MyCategory
Get-Counter : Cannot find any performance counter sets on the localhost computer that match the following: MyCategory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -ListSet MyCategory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingCounterSetsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
```

Curiously trying to directly retrieve a counter by name gives this error:

```
>Get-Counter -Counter "\MyCategory\MyCounter"
Get-Counter : Internal performance counter API call failed. Error: c0000bb8.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Counter "\MyCategory\MyCounter"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
```

But...when I ran it in a new Powershell session (even as non-admin) it worked just fine.

So in answer to my question: PerformanceCounterCategory and "counter set" do appear to be the same thing.